# Flash videos not playing on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: browser, osx-lion, flash-player

I'm unable to play any of online videos (e.g. YouTube) on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3.

I tried the following:

- Searched on the internet googling, and tried most what was suggested in forums, but nothing worked for me.
- Installed and tried other browsers (Firefox, Chrome) apart from Safari.
- Opened all the browsers in 32-bit mode.
- Uninstalled and re-installed latest Flash (11.x.x.235) compatible for Lion.
- Tried another user account.

How could this be resolved?

Comment: Does other flash work (besides flash containing video)?
Also does it give you any error message? (for example, does it ask you to install flash, or is it just blank)?

Comment: @Yitzchak: I was not satisfied with the answers and was expecting more suitable. If you wish I'll simply accept them.

Comment: @David: I am not sure how to check if it's flash or not, but youtube and a game site is not playing the videos. But while playing youtube, it's playing the `ad` properly but when it finished the ad it's not playing the actual video leaving in a `black screen`.